# Flutter : AnimationController - without a button to control it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I made an animation with `AnimationController`, and I want it to start when the user open the app and when the animation ends, the user go to another page without pressing any button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in your `StatefulWidget` subclass.

```
AnimationController _controller; // member variable

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));

  // start the animation when this page opens
  _controller.forward().then((value) {
    // animation is finished, you can now go to any page
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => YourPage())); // changed
  });

  _controller.addListener(() { 
    // this is your listener, you can also control lots of things from here
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the replay , but it can not find the other page : 

E/flutter ( 7773): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/home.dart", null) in the _WidgetsAppState. 

Before you unswer me, i use a setState() 
setState(() {
    if (controller.isAnimating)
       controller.stop();

     else{
      controller.reverse(
       from: controller.value == 0.0
        ? 1.0
       :Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/home.dart"));
      }
});

it gives me the same result, but i can't go to another page

Comment: Check out the updated answer, I used `Navigator.push` this time.